# In python how can I find if the given time is between a range

Tags: python

I need to execute a code between a set time every day. So I need to find if the current time is between a time range.

```
hralarm=False
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if  datetime.time(hour=14,minute=40) > now  > datetime.time(hour=14,minute=50):
   hralarm=True
else :
   hralarm=False
```

The hralarm flag is always returning a False. The now variable returns 14:46:22.994000 . Should I format 'now' to not have the seconds and microseconds and maybe that is why the comparison is not happening correctly?..I am new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because now > 14:40 (not 14:40 > now) and now < 14:50 (not now > 14:50).

Comment: Your condition can never be satisfied.. It cannot be earlier than 14:40 and later than 14:50 at the same time

Comment: oh my a silly mistake...thankyou for pointing it out.....sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your comparison operators mixed up. You are asking if the current time is **before** 14:40:

```
datetime.time(hour=14,minute=40) > now   # only times *smaller* will match
```

and **after** 14:50:

```
now > datetime.time(hour=14,minute=50)  # only times *greater* will match
```

No clock time can ever match both those conditions at the same time.

The following test would work to find times between 14:40 and 14:50 however:

```
if datetime.time(14, 40) < now < datetime.time(14, 50):
# 14:40 must be smaller          and 14:50 must be greater
```

Remember that the 'pointed' end of a `<` or `>` points to the smaller value.

Note that the comparison operators already produce `True` or `False`, you can assign that *directly* to your `hralarm` variable rather than use `if` to confirm it for you:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
hralarm = datetime.time(14, 40) < now < datetime.time(14, 50)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
hralarm=False
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()

if  datetime.time(hour=14,minute=40) < now  < datetime.time(hour=14,minute=50):
   hralarm=True
else :
  hralarm=False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
import datetime

hralarm=False
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()

time1 = datetime.time(14, 40, 0)
time2 = datetime.time(14, 50, 0)

if  (time1.hour >= now.hour and time1.minute < now.minute) and  (now.hour  <= time2.hour and now.minute  < time2.minute):
   hralarm=True
else :
   hralarm=False

print(hralarm)
```

Comment: Python comparison operators can be *chained*, which is what the OP is doing. `timeobject1 > now > timeobject2` *is exactly the same thing* as `timeobject1 > now and now > timeobject2`, except that `now` is only evaluated once. Using `and` here is entirely redundant. And you still make the exact same mistake with the operators, your test won't match either.